# Unable to upgrade from 16.04.6 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 16.04.6 to 18.04 but I keep getting the message:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

But there aren't any updates to install. I have done the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And I still get that message. What else can I do to upgrade?

Comment: I would recommend to do a clean new install, it's usually more reliable than upgrade. Don't forget to backup your important data before doing it.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262708/edit) to show us the complete output of those four commands.

Comment: Please run the commands and copy all the output (of one command at a time) using the text copy feature of the terminal. Then paste then directly into your question above using the [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262708/edit). Finally format the pasted commands and output as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: [This](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-20-x/1420/2) is from a Lubuntu forum and I don't want to duplicate work. It was authored by @guiverc and gives a pretty good foundation/explanation of where you were, how you got there, and how to get from where you are to where you want to be.